# What's the deal with the Hellboy film rights?

Tags: copyright, hellboy

The first Hellboy movie by Guillermo del Toro had the same production company as the second, Revolution Studios -- they had just been distributed by different people (Sony and Universal, respectively).  Then the reboot at Lionsgate was credited to the same producers as the other two, but at a completely different production company -- Millennium Films, which, when I looked it up on Wikipedia, it claimed fell defunct long before 2019.

How is all that possible?  Also, when do the rights to Hellboy expire at Lionsgate?

Comment: This is IMHO trivia, plus it is likely unanswerable anyway since we're not privy to the behind the scenes going-ons WRT how these projects came to be. Plus things like which company gets credited in what way is part of legalese and rules.